# Adding a new lexer to scintilla/scite (...and eventually wxPython StyledTextCtrl)

Tags: lexer, scintilla, scite, umn-mapserver

Has anyone of you successfully added a lexer to scintilla?

I have been following the short instructions at http://www.scintilla.org/SciTELexer.html - and even discovered the secret extra instructions at http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#BuildingScintilla (Changing Set of Lexers)

Everything compiles, and I can add the lexer to SciTE just fine, but my ColouriseMapfileDoc method just does not get called (a printf does not produce output). If I add the same code to e.g. the ColouriseLuaDoc lexer, everything is fine (a printf *does* produce output).

Specifically I have

1. In `scintilla/include/Scintilla.iface`, added `val SCLEX_MAPFILE=99`
2. And any lexical class IDs
3. In the scintilla/include directory run `HFacer.py` and confirmed that the `SciLexer.h` file has changed.
4. Created `LexMapfile.cxx` with a `ColouriseMapfileDoc` function
5. At the end of the file associated the lexer ID and name with the function:

   LexerModule lmMapfile(SCLEX_MAPFILE, ColouriseMapfileDoc, "mapfile");
6. Run `LexGen.py` to generate all the makefiles (as per the secret instructions)
7. Created a new SciTE properties file by cloning `scite/src/others.properties`
8. Set up some styles
9. In `scite/src/SciTEGlobal.properties` added `$(filter.conf)` to the definition of `open.filter`.
10. Added this language to the Language menu of SciTE,
11. Built both Scintilla and SciTE.
12. Grumbled and cursed.

What am I doing wrong, except maybe step 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone reads this question in the future - you will also have to add a line
`import yourformat` in `SciTEGlobal.properties`. That's the undocumented step 9b.

Answer (score 3):

> In case someone reads this question in the future - you will also have to add a line import 
>   yourformat in SciTEGlobal.properties. That's the undocumented step 9b.

This step is no longer required.  I compiled 3.2.2 and this was done with import *.  The rest of the steps are still complete and relevant though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wring one lexer directly in `scintilla/lexer/LexOthers.cxx` as described in http://www.scintilla.org/SciTELexer.html.
For scite 3.2.3 the lacking step 5b is that you need to add `LINK_LEXER(lmYouLexerMod);` in `scintilla/src/Catalogue.cxx`.