# Display styled json in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, syntax-highlighting

I have a wxpython application that display json in a TextCtrl.  How can I use StyledTextCtrl to display that json properly highlighted?
Is is just a one-liner change or much bigger?

Btw I created jsyntaxpane and IT IS one liner to highlight several languages.  Too bad I need wxPython now.

Answer (score 1):

StyledTextCtrl should work for you. But it doesn't have built-in lexer for JSON.

I'd try options in the following order:

- pass `stc.STC_LEX_AUTOMATIC` to StyledTextCtrl's `SetLexer()` and see if it highlights your json correctly
- choose (try one by one) a lexer from [built-in lexers](http://wiki.wxpython.org/StyledTextCtrl%20Lexer%20Quick%20Reference#StyledTextCtrl_Quick_Reference) that will show your json correctly
- try other components, like:

  - [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/index.html)
  - [editra](http://editra.org/)
  - ...
- add your own custom lexer/hightlighter, see

  - [Python wx.stc custom highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807276/python-wx-stc-custom-highlighting)
  - [Adding a new lexer to scintilla/scite (...and eventually wxPython StyledTextCtrl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297567/adding-a-new-lexer-to-scintilla-scite-and-eventually-wxpython-styledtextctrl)

Hope that helps.

Comment: It sure helps :-)  STC is not as hard as it seems.  Just lacking a bit in some docs and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python 3.7 and a lexer for JSON is available. You can use the below.

```
stc.StyledTextCtrl.__init__(self, parent)
self.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_JSON)
```

Adding to this, there are other properties which might be useful while using StyledTextCtrl for JSON. These properties are used for font sizing and color for various fields that are part of a normal JSON.

```
self.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_JSON_DEFAULT, "fore:#000000,face:%(helv)s,size:%(size)d" % fonts)
self.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_JSON_NUMBER, "fore:#007F7F,size:%(size)d" % fonts)
self.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_JSON_KEYWORD, "fore:#007F7F,bold,size:%(size)d" % fonts)
self.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_JSON_STRING, "fore:#7F0000,size:%(size)d" % fonts)
self.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_JSON_PROPERTYNAME, "fore:#FF5733,size:%(size)d" % fonts)
```